# Number comma separator for String numbers in Java

Tags: java, format

I know there is a numberFormat func for double type input, but I want a numberFormat for String type input.

Are there any way to add comma separators for String numbers,

such as `"1000", "302343"` etc. Not `1000` or `302343`.

I don't want to convert the String input into `int` or double because precision might change after type casting.

**Example**:

```
input: "1000"

output: "1,000"
```

Comment: If you don't want to convert it to a number first, you'll have to roll your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html):

```
String num = "1000";
System.out.println( NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(new Integer(num)) );
```

Using [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)):

```
String.format("%,d", new Integer(num))
```

Output:

```
1,000
```

Comment: Thank you for the and. But I forgot to say I don't want to convert the String input to int or double because precision might change after type casting.
Are there still any smart ways? Or I need to implement a func for it?